# Starting an Oracle database without a spfile & pfile?

Tags: oracle

How can I start an Oracle database if both the spfile and pfile are not present, and a backup is also not available?

Comment: what happens when you issue the startup command?

Comment: Check your alert log for the last time the database was started successfully as the non-default parameters are logged there... You can use that as the starting point for manually creating your pfile.  After your database is up, do yourself a favor and configure controlfile + spfile autobackup from RMAN so that a backup of these files is taken anytime you backup your database (and/or archivelogs).

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with a basic `pfile` file like this:

```
SID.__db_cache_size=180355072
SID.__java_pool_size=71303168
SID.__large_pool_size=4194304
SID.__oracle_base='/u01/app/oracle'#ORACLE_BASE set from environment
SID.__pga_aggregate_target=335544320
SID.__sga_target=1001088640
SID.__shared_io_pool_size=0
SID.__shared_pool_size=419430400
SID.__streams_pool_size=50331648
*.audit_trail='DB_EXTENDED'
*.compatible='11.2.0.0.0'
*.control_files='/u01/oradata/SID/control01.ctl','/u01/oradata/SID/control02.ctl','/u01/oradata/SID/control03.ctl'
*.core_dump_dest='/u01/app/oracle/admin/SID/cdump'
*.db_domain='your.domain'
*.db_name='SID'
*.db_recovery_file_dest='/u01/oradata/SID/flash_recovery_area'
*.db_recovery_file_dest_size=1000G
*.db_unique_name='SID02'
*.pga_aggregate_target=335544320
*.sga_max_size=1005306368
*.sga_target=1001088640
*.timed_statistics=TRUE
*.undo_management='AUTO'
*.undo_retention=900
*.undo_tablespace='UNDOTS02'
```

Change the values so that they reflect the values (at least replace `SID` with your SID) that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can start your database in nomount mode without parameter file, control file and datafile.

Steps:

2. `rman target /`
3. `startup nomount force;`

Oracle will use current $ORACLE_SID variable as SID and default parameters for parameter file.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Marco answer, after creating manual pfile, you should create spfile from it using: `CREATE SPFILE FROM PFILE = '/location/to/your/pfile'`

Some information about FPIEL and SPFILE

PFILE

> A PFILE is a static, client side text file. This file normally resides
>   on the server. However in case you would like to start oracle from a
>   remote machine, you will need a local copy of the PFILE in that
>   machine.
>
> This file can be edited with a standard text editor like notepad or vi
>   editor. This file will be commonly referred as INIT.ORA file.

SPFILE

> SPFILE (Server parameter file) is a persistent server side binary
>   file. SPFILE should only be modified through “ALTER SYSTEM SET”
>   command . Editing an SPFILE directly will corrupt the file and the
>   start up of the database or instance will not be possible.
>
> As SPFILe is a server side binary file,  local copy of the PFILE is
>   not required to start oracle from a remote machine.

Advantages of SPFILE compared to PFILE

- A SPFILE doesn't need a local copy of  the pfile to start  oracle
  from a remote machine.  Thus eliminates configuration problems.
- SPFILE  is a binary file and modification to that can only be done
  through ALTER SYSTEM SET command.
- As SPFILE is maintained by the server, human errors can be eliminated
  as the parameters are checked before modification in SPFILE
- It is easy  to locate SPFILE as it is stored in a central location
- Changes to the parameters in SPFILE will take immediate effect
  without restart of the instance i.e. Dynamic change of parameters is
  possible
- SPFILE can be backed up by RMAN

Reference:
https://sapbasisdurgaprasad.blogspot.com/2011/07/difference-between-pfile-and-spfile-in.html